# Opening modal with materialize in ASPX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, materialize

I'm currently learning frontend design with ASPX and materialize, but I'm stuck trying to open a modal from codebehind.

I already tried the href and data-target methods, but I would like more control as to which conditions I need to open which modal and what kind of text I want to show (I'll probably need several different modals in one page).

I know that I need to create a javascript code somewhere in my page that would let me open modals at will in codebehind with a code like this one:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

but I don't really know how or where implement the js code.

My most accurate finding was this: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5002 but didn't helped me to solve my problem, as it appears to be something used in bootstrap exclusively and they say it creates problems when combined.

Comment: If you're learning something...why are you learning Web Forms? A dying and outdated framework?

Comment: That was not exactly my call, but anyway, I'm trying to solve my question about it.

And if you can point me to more modern frameworks similar to ASPX, I'll gladly research them. I'm actually liking to program in ASPX more than I liked php, for instance.

Comment: No, you *don't* want something similar to ASPX. Web Forms is gross. ViewState, UpdatePanel, mangled ID's, it's all a mess. If you want to use ASP.NET, then your best best is ASP.NET MVC, or writing a Single Page Application backed by ASP.NET Web API.